# Passing an array of Strings to DeclareNewCommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse

I need to pass an array of Strings to a command as a keyed value (or named value).
my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{myCommandKeys}{array}{\def\mm@array{#1}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myCommand}{m}
{%
  \begingroup%
      % ========= KEY DEFAULTS + new ones =========
      \setkeys{myCommandKeys}{array={{nothing,to,see,here}},#1}%

      \def\array{\mm@array}

      \pgfmathparse{dim(\array)}
      \edef\arraylength{\pgfmathresult}

      \pgfmathparse{int(\arraylength-1)}
      \edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

      \node at (0, 5) {array passed: \array};
      \node at (0, 4) {number of items: \arraylength};
      \node at (0, 3) {last index: \lastIndex};

      \foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} {
            \node at (0,1-\i) {item at index \i: \array[\i]};
      }       
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myCommand{array={why,you,no,working!?}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output I am getting right now is:

[image]

and the error I get is

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `why' (in 'dim(why,you,no,working!?)').
```

Obviously, the array length should be 4, last index 3 and items displayed (one per line of output) should be:

```
why 
you
no
working!?
```

Comment: The problem here is working with strings. Moreover, indexing such an array doesn't work out-of-the-box via `<array>[.]`.

Comment: hi @Werner, can you please point out to any resource where i can read up on this? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to surround your array elements with `"` to tell pgf that those are strings and not function names. The following does work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{myCommandKeys}{array}{\def\mm@array{#1}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myCommand}{m}
{%
  \begingroup%
      % ========= KEY DEFAULTS + new ones =========
      \setkeys{myCommandKeys}{array={{nothing,to,see,here}},#1}%

      \def\array{{\mm@array}}

      \pgfmathparse{dim(\array)}
      \edef\arraylength{\pgfmathresult}

      \pgfmathparse{int(\arraylength-1)}
      \edef\lastIndex{\pgfmathresult}

      \node at (0, 5) {array passed: \array};
      \node at (0, 4) {number of items: \arraylength};
      \node at (0, 3) {last index: \lastIndex};

      \foreach \i in {0,...,\lastIndex} {
        \node at (0,1-\i) {item at index \i:
          \pgfmathparse{\array[\i]}\pgfmathresult};
      }       
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myCommand{array={"why","you","no","working!?"}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much, skillmon! I had quotes earlier and that didn't work either. i have now realized my main mistake - I was using \def\array{\mm@array} while it should be what you have done - \def\array{{\mm@array}}. thanks a tonne!!

Comment: when I pass an array with a single item, it doesn't work. example: \myCommand{array={"hello!!!"}} instead it displays each character separately (8 items). any idea why?

Comment: @gauravgupta change the definition `\def\array{{\mm@array}}` to `\def\array{{\mm@array,}}`. The trailing comma doesn't change the number of elements, but this way, pgf knows what should be an element (empty elements at the end of an array are ignored).

Comment: when i change the definition to `\def\array{{\mm@array,}}`, i get the correct output but there is an error (`Undefined control sequence`) for every time I invoke the command. any workaround for that?

Comment: @gauravgupta sadly I don't have a workaround for that :( You could use `expl3` instead of `pgf` to parse that array, though.